# Nintex forms get logged in user display name and current list name

Tags: nintex-workflow

In Nintex forms I am writing a bit of JavaScript and for that I need some properties of the current list, like the list name, current list item title. How do I get this using JavaScript using Nintex forms? In the JavaScript section there is a separate area called, "Insert Reference" but I don't know how to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, enter something like this in the Custom Javascript setting of your form-

```
NWF$(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log();
});
```

Then with the cursor between the parentheses of the **console.log** line, enter a quote, click on the **Insert Reference** button and pick your variable, then insert another quote.

The result will look like-

```
NWF$(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log("List_Name");
});
```

List_Name will be in red text.

Things to watch out for are-

- The Nintex symbol is inserted as literal text, not a string Javascript variable, so you do need to put the quotes around it or Javascript will try to interpret the value as a variable name.
- If you like to write your code in a separate text editor, then paste it into the form (which makes a lot of sense), you'll have to re-insert the Nintex variables as they lose their "magicness" when pasted in as text.